# How To Format String At JSP Page using "Out.Format(Format,String Var)" Error "The method format(String, String) is undefined for the type JspWrite"?

Tags: java, jsp, format

Hi i am trying to format string at JSP page it gave me error as i mentioned in title my code is,

```
    String header="";
    header = 12-29-2011 15;
    out.format("%0$s:00:00\n",header);
```

it result in error "The method format(String, String) is undefined for the type JspWrite"

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your header is of type string and your remember the double quote, how about the assignment of the date to header, why didn't you double quote it?

Comment: i tried it with out double quote the result is same !

Comment: also, the error said method is undefined for the type jspwriter, read more here as that method is not defined by the class JspWriter. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html

Comment: so how would i debug it in my code ?

Comment: one way to do it is that, first, you format the date using another java class, and then you print out the formatted string using jspwriter.

Comment: can you please let me know that thing in my code here.. .

Comment: salman, read the suggested answer.

Comment: @Jasonw thanks for your cooperation i will try then let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `string.format()` or `SimpleDateFormat` and print the resutls using `out.print().`